# Groovy replace everything after character

Tags: groovy

I need to replace all content after a specific character in **groovy** with the value of a parameter,

my string is :

```
env.APP_VERSION="1.9"
```

And I would like to replace everything after the **=** sign with the value of a certain parameter let's call it **$PARAM**.

I was able to trim everything after the = sign,

but not replace it...

```
result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf('APP_VERSION='));
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is, indeed, to use regex. It should include:

- `(?<==)` - A *positive lookbehind* for `=`.
- `.*` - Match all chars (up to the end).

So the script can look like below:

```
src = 'env.APP_VERSION="1.9"'
PARAM = '"xyz"'
res = src.replaceFirst(/(?<==).*/, PARAM)
```

Another solution is to **split** the string on `=` and "mount" the result string
from:

- The first string from split result.
- `=` char.
- Your replacement string.

This time the processing part of the script should be:

```
spl = src.split('=')
res = spl[0] + '=' + PARAM
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing about your original intentions you have 2 options:

1) Do not reinvent the wheel and use GString magic:

```
String ver = '1.9'
String result = "env.APP_VERSION=\"$ver\""
```

2) use some regex:

```
 result = result.replaceFirst( /APP_VERSION="[^"]+"/, 'APP_VERSION="something"' )
```